# Index of hovered item in JavaFX combo box

Tags: javafx, combobox

It is possible to get the index of the list item I am hovering over in the listview of a combo box? I have tried to place an event filter on on the popup content of the combo box. Within the event filter I try to get the selected item index but the index is always -1.

Comment: Use a cell factory and place a listener on the cell

Comment: @James_D already pointed you into the correct direction, also note: debugging questions ("within the event filter I try but ..") do _require_ a [mcve]

Answer (score 0):

This is how you might implement what James_D said in the comments:

```
package example.stackoverflow;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.IntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleIntegerProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class ComboIndex extends Application {
    private IntegerProperty hoverIndex = new SimpleIntegerProperty(-1);
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
    
    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Label label = new Label();
        label.textProperty().bind(Bindings.format("Index: %d", hoverIndex));
        ComboBox<String> combo = new ComboBox<>(FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                "Zero", "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven"));
        combo.setCellFactory(this::makeCell);
        var root = new VBox(12, label, combo);
        root.setPadding(new Insets(16));
        var scene = new Scene(root);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("ComboBox Index");
        primaryStage.show();
    }
 
    private ListCell<String> makeCell(ListView<String> param) {
        var cell = new javafx.scene.control.cell.ComboBoxListCell<String>();
        cell.hoverProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, hovered) -> {
            hoverIndex.set(hovered ? cell.getIndex() : -1);
        });
        return cell;
    }


}
```

Comment: the asker choose to not clarify the requirement - so one assumption is as good (or bad) as the other ;) Here a problem might be that the hoverIndex is not unset on exit. Personally, I would go for listening to the cell's hover property vs low-level mouse events.

Comment: @kleopatra good point.  I've changed it to use the hover property and be -1 when nothing is hovered.